# Is this a good approach to setting the authorization header for calling an API from a web app?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4

We have a web application secured with IdentityServer that accesses multiple APIs also secured by IdentityServer. I would like to provide client libraries for the APIs distributed via NuGet and I want to consistently handle supplying the access token. It appears that this will work but I'm not sure if it's a good idea. My main concern is that it might cause the HttpClient to be created each time its accessed. It appears that I get a new instance every time but that also appears to be the case if don't do any configuration when registering the HttpClient.

The `ITokenProvider` implementation would be responsible for retrieving, caching, and refreshing the access token as needed.

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMyClient, MyClient>((serviceProvider, httpClient) =>
{
    var tokenProvider = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ITokenProvider>();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokenProvider.AccessToken);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is NO. You can set a header in the delegate but it won't work if you need to make an async call to get data such as an access token. A better approach is to create a custom `DelegatingHandler` implementation as described in [this blog post](https://blog.joaograssi.com/typed-httpclient-with-messagehandler-getting-accesstokens-from-identityserver/). My version is something like this:

```
public class MyTokenClientMessageHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly IMyTokenClient _myTokenClient;

    public MyTokenClientMessageHandler(IMyTokenClient myTokenClient)
    {
        _myTokenClient = myTokenClient;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var accessToken = await _myTokenClient.GetToken();
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

and register it with

```
services.AddTransient<MyTokenClientMessageHandler>();
services.AddHttpClient<IMyClient, MyClient>(httpClient =>
{
    // set base URL etc.
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<MyTokenClientMessageHandler>();
```